# How to get array from nested documents, mongo

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm busy self learning mongo and not sure if my way of thinking is wrong.
I've read the documents, but I cant find info regarding my question.

eg doc:

```
{
    "name" : "doc1",
    "items" : [
        {
            "name" : "item1",
            "itemarray": [a,b,c]
        },
        {
            "name" : "item2",
            "itemarray" : [a,b,c]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "doc2",
    "items" : [
        {
            "name" : "item1",
            "itemarray": [a,b,c]
        },
        {
            "name" : "item2",
            "itemarray": [a,b,c]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I want to do:**

*Assuming I know the names*

Within doc1 items, in item1, return the itemarray (or even better, check if an item is in that array).

> My end goal is to see if a item is in a specific itemarray by either
> returning the whole array and checking it manually, or by checking
> within the query

**What I have tried**

So far I can get all the items by using this:

`collection.find({name: "doc1"}, 'items')`

Which is fine for small scale, because I take the results and loop through the array, but when things get huge I feel this will not be viable just to check if a item is in an array.

Another one is this:

`collection.findOne({ "name": "doc1"}, {"items.itemarray" : 1})`

Close, but not what I am looking for. It returns all item arrays in doc1, I only want itemarray in item1. The return looks like this:

```
"items": [
            {
                "itemarray": [
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "c"
                ]
            },
            {
                "itemarray": [
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "c"
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Thank you for your time, any guidance is massively appreciated

PS: Any tips on improving questions are also welcome :)

Comment: See this in MongoDB Manual for some ideas about querying an array: [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have seen that, but I need to specifically target the first document

Comment: You can try using `$elemMatch` operator. Note that there are two operators with that name - one is a query operator and the other is a projection operator.